# Modal in front of a modal in react native, not picking up state

Tags: react-native

I am using the Modal component from react-native to creat a slide up menu for users to select. The issue with this is, if you wish to dim the background and animate with 'slide', it does this ugly thing of sliding a dimmed box up the screen, instead of dimming the whole background THEN sliding the view in.

So I tried to solve for this by using two Modals. One modal for the dark background to fade in and second modal to slide in with the menu with a transparent background.

This actually works, but when `this.doneDayPicker` changes the state of `this.state.showModalDayPicker` so both modals are no longer visible, `<DarkModal>` still appears. I'm left with `<DarkModal>` permanently on the screen.

What can I change to let `<DarkModal>` dissapear when `this.state.showModalDayPicker` is changed?

```
return (
      <DarkModal visible={this.state.showModalDayPicker}>
      <GoalModalScreen
        visible={this.state.showModalDayPicker}
        done={this.doneDayPicker}
        title='Health benefits'
        height={this.state.goalModalHeight}
      >
      {this.flatList()}
      </GoalModalScreen>
      </DarkModal>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I would say this is because there is no done property on DarkModal like goalModalScreen?

Or use a Ternary Operator

```
{this.state.showModalDayPicker ? <DarkModal> : undefined}
```

You might also setup DarkModal's own toggle in state.

```
{this.state.toggleDarkModal ? <DarkModal> : undefined}
```

Comment: The function passed in done 'this.doneDayPicker' changes the state 'this.state.showModalDayPicker' to true. If the user triggers this.doneDayPicker by pressing a button in GoalModalScreen, it should be enough to make both modals invisible, since they read off the same state, but it doesn't. I've tried making a separate toggle in state but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you wrap both modals into a View then use a Ternary to only show this view based on ShowModalDayPicker? I think the issue is the double nested Modals (which I know is what you want) but React native is super picky

Comment: I've actually wrapped both with TouchableOpacity, I took it out of the code to make it brief. thanks

Comment: Well my last advice would be to modularize these modals into a separate component, and then use Ternary to render this component (with both modals) on your toggle.